# Epsilon delta proof min

Tags: calculus, limits

http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/DeltaEpsilonProofs03.htm

I've been studying these épsilon delta proofs. In the non-linear case, he gets:

$$\delta=\min\left\{5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}},-5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}\right\}$$

Well, I know that these $\delta$ are not equal the opposite of the other, but it has shown that $x$ must be within the range covered by these two deltas. Well, I already have bounded the $x-a$ (in this case, $x-5$) in therms of $\epsilon$, so it should work that for any given $\epsilon$, i could get only the  $-5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$. Why I have to get the minimum?

Comment: because u want to take within $\delta$ from $(-5)$ and since all $x's$ within the range $ (5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} ,-5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}})$ do the job,  u want to make sure you take the minimal value so that so that when you take $|x-c|<\delta$ you will still be within that interval

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 so why can't I just select the minimum delta value and use it in the proof?

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 at the proof part, he assumes $-\delta < x-c < \delta$ and then substitutes $(5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} ,-5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}})$ like delta was equal to both of them, but one is not the opposite of the other!

Comment: the proof uses :$-5+\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}<-\delta<x<\delta$

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 so why he substitutes $5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ in the $- \delta$ part?

Comment: check back the proof they used $-5+\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ as lower bound for $-\delta$

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 I've plotted the two deltas, and the $-5+\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ is always the minimum of the two deltas (when $\epsilon > 0$). Why don't simply use this delta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He takes the minimum so that he can use the following two inequalities.
$$
\delta \leq 5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} \\
\delta \leq -5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}
$$
The first inequality above can be written as
$$
-5 + \sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} \leq -\delta.
$$
So the proof uses these inequalities to get
$$
-5 + \sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} \leq -\delta < x - 5 < \delta \leq -5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}
$$
which is the inequality he intended to get (as you can see when he worked backwards). Hopefully that clears up why he needed to take $\delta$ as the minimum of the two quantities.

Comment: I though $5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ should be LESS than $\delta$, now I'm confused!

Comment: Also, he says that the delta must be the minimum of the two, bue then in the proof, he uses the two deltas. Why???

Comment: No, $\delta$ has to be less than $5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ in order to have the inequality $-5 + \sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} < -\delta$. But he also needs the inequality $\delta < -5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ in the proof. That's why he takes the minimum of the two quantities. In the proof there is only one $\delta$, but there are two $\epsilon$. The second epsilon is a way to work around the fact that $5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ may be undefined if the $\epsilon$ is too big.

Comment: I don't understand why there's only one delta. For me, $5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ is not the opposite of $-5 + \sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$. I completely understood the second epsilon. I also don't understand why we have to define delta as the minimum of the two candidates, since $-5+\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ is always the minimum delta (i've plotted the two ones for $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: @user108425 There is always one $\delta$. Also $-5+\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ (as you mentioned in your last sentence) is not even in the expression for $\delta$. I think you meant $5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$.Anyway, you may be right that one of the quantity is always smaller than the other. In that case you can just choose that for $\delta$. However, there is no harm in writing $\delta$ as the minimum of the two quantities. It might be even better since you don't need to bother about which quantity is smaller and in the end we only care that a $\delta$ exists.

Comment: I pretty understand this, but in the 'proof part', he uses two diferent deltas. I don't understand why :(

Comment: @user108425 I honestly don't see where two different $\delta$ were used. Can you point out which line this was done?

Comment: In the proof part, he says that we must show a $\delta$ that satisfies $-\delta < x-c < \delta$. Then he substitute the $-\delta$ and $\delta$ by this: $-5+\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon_2}{3}} < x-5 < -5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon_2}{3}}$. He used two diferent deltas. One is $-5+\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon_2}{3}}$ and the other is $-5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon_2}{3}}$ when in fact we can choose only one $\delta$ and use its opposite as $-\delta$. Cleary one is not the opposite of the other.

Comment: @user108425 NO. He chose only _one_ $\delta$ as $\delta=\min\left\{5-\sqrt{25-\frac{\epsilon}{3}},-5+\sqrt{25+\frac{\epsilon}{3}}\right\}$. Therefore we can extract two inequalities from this: $\delta \leq 5-\sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$ and $\delta \leq -5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$. The first one can be rewritten as $-5 + \sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} \leq -\delta$. I explained this clearly in my answer. Since $-\delta < x - 5 < \delta$ we can put it altogether to get $-5 + \sqrt{25-\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}} \leq -\delta < x - 5 < \delta \leq -5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$.

Comment: Now I understood. Is this exactly what he did, right? Well, I understand this now. A last question, I promise: could I use the smaller delta and complete the proof, right?

Comment: @user108425 Yes, you can just use the smaller one as the $\delta$ which is I think $-5+\sqrt{25+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is because $\delta$ has to be acceptable in the worst case.  Say we are proving $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=L$ and for (the given) $\epsilon$ we are within $\epsilon$ over the interval $\delta \in (-1,0.1)$  The definition of limit is symmetric:  it says whenever $x$ is within $\delta$ of $0$, then $|f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$ so we have to shrink the interval to make it symmetric, so our answer should be *within* $\delta \in (-0.1,0.1)$.  This sounds restrictive, but it is not.  One can prove that symmetric limits leads to the same thing as asymmetric limits and every interval includes a symmetric interval.